# VueJS 2 and Vue Resource - Chrome Crashes (infinite loop?)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, vue.js, vue-resource

Using VueJS2 with vue-resource

Building a trait for handling CRUD functions.

My model data is stored in data at key selectedClientModel (for example), and so, the component that uses this Trait defines the key to store the data  ie >>

```
this.dataModel = "selectedClientModel";
```

and sets the resourceUri appropriately. ie>>

```
this.resourceUri = "/api/admin/clients";
```

So, the Trait is below.....

```
    updateModel() {
        var vm = this;
        var model = this.$data[this.dataModel];
        this.$http.put(this.resourceUri + '/' + model.id, model).then(function(response) {
            alert('success');
        }, function (response) {
            alert('failure');
        });
    },
```

When I run this, chrome crashes, so I installed FF for Devs and found the following:

```
InternalError: too much recursion
Stack trace:
reactiveGetter@http://oriondas.app/js/retailer-orders.js line 103 > eval:1101:11
_merge@http://oriondas.app/js/retailer-orders.js line 230 > eval:413:1
_merge@http://oriondas.app/js/retailer-orders.js line 230 > eval:420:13
_merge@http://oriondas.app/js/retailer-orders.js line 230 > eval:420:13
...
```

At line 103 is:

```
eval("/*!\n * Vue.js v2.0.3\n * (c) 2014-2016 Evan You\n * Released under the MIT License.\n */\n(function (global, factory) {\n   true ? module.exports = factory() :\n  typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(factory) :\n  (global.Vue = fac .......
```

At line 230 is:

```
eval("/*!\n * vue-resource v1.0.3\n * https://github.com/vuejs/vue-resource\n * Released under the MIT License.\n */\n\n'use strict';\n\n/**\n * Promises/A+ polyfill v1.1.4 (https://github.com/bramstein/promis)\n */\n\nvar RESOLVED = 0;\nvar REJECTED = 1;\nvar PENDING = 2;\n\nfunction Promise$1(executor) {\n\n    this.state = PENDING;\n    this.value = undefined;\n    this.deferred = [];\n\n    var promise = this;\n\n    try {\n        executor(function (x) {\n            promise.resolve(x);\n        }, fu .....
```

I have no idea why this is turning into an infinite loop... any help would be greatly appreciated.

(FYI, I am using Vue-resource for create and delete and they work perfectly fine....)

Comment: Do you have any watchers on this component?

Comment: What is var model = this.$data[this.dataModel]; referring to? data in the Vue instance? It's hard to say without seeing the whole component and relevant parts of the Vue instance.

Comment: How is `updateModel` used?

Comment: I put in all the details I could an posted it here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41289787/vuejs2-with-vue-resource-creates-infinite-loop)